# I'm trying to identify this small bush or tree in Lake Placid Florida

Tags: identification, trees, leaves, shrubs

Anybody know what this is? Seems to grow thick, fast and well in this very sandy soil. but not sure I see any that are very big or mature.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

did some searching and wonder if:

Gray sallow? Basket Willow? Cuban Jute?

Wonder how big and thick it grows?